# 'Cells-like method for TDataSet' OR 'No basic data-table in Delphi?'

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe7

I need to hold some data in a table. So, I built my own table (non-visual). The most important feature I need is the ability to quickly read/write any 'cell' I want, exactly as you do it in TStringGrid with Cells[Col, Row]. My table consists in one single neat PAS file.

This is what it implements, just to give you an idea about what I need:

```
TYPE
 TMyTable= class(TObject)
  private
    FRows: array of TStringDynArray;    { The format is [Row, Col]. Row[0] stores the header! }
  protected
  public
    FileName: string;
    constructor Create; virtual;
    procedure Clear;    virtual;
    procedure Sort(SortCol: Integer);
    function  ImportCSV (TSL: TStringList; Separator: char= ','): Boolean;  

    { I/O }
    procedure SaveToFile   (CONST aFileName: string);
    function  LoadFromFile (CONST aFileName: string): Boolean;

    { Add col }
    function  AddRow   : Integer;
    function  AddColumn     (CONST ColHeader: string): Integer;    overload;
    function  InsertColumn  (CONST ColHeader: string; AfterColumn: Integer): Integer;
    procedure InsertRow     (AfterRow: Integer);

    { Remove }
    procedure RemoveEmptyCols;
    procedure RemoveRow (aRow: Integer);
    procedure RemoveCol (aCol: Integer);

    { Find col }
    function  FindColumn      (const ColumnName: string): Integer;
    function  FindText        (Column: Integer; Text: string): Integer;  overload;

    { Access }
    procedure NumberRows;                                                        { Show the number of each row. If this column doesn't exist, then create it }

    property  Row[Index: Integer]: TStringDynArray read getRow        write setRow;
    property  Col[Index: Integer]: TStringDynArray read getColumn     write setColumn;

    property  ColCount: Integer                    read getColCount   write setColCount;
    property  RowCount: Integer                    read getRowCount   write setRowCount;  { Indexed in 0. So, if I have 10 rows, and I want to access the last on, I do Row[9] }

    property  Cell        [Rw, Cl: Integer]: string        read getCell write setCell;
    property  CellByColumn[Rw: Integer; ColName: string]: string read getCellByColumn write setCellByColumn;
 end;
```

I am interested in 'upgrading' to a better system and it seems that [TDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TDataSet_Methods) does something somehow similar. However, it seems it does not offer direct cell access - which is quite amazing because cell access is such a basic feature (it may be just my opinion). 
Is it feasible to implement this without loss of speed? I never used BDE or TDataSet until now. TDataSet offers a whole array of functions that are related to DB. But I don't want a database system; only a simple table to hold data in it (more like a CSV file). I also don't want to 'drag' with me the whole DB overhead (like BDE, etc).

UPDATE
Well, it doesn't have to be TDataSet... The more I look at it, the more I think that it adds a lot of overhead. It could be any Pascal class that can hold a simple data table. It is amazing that Delphi does not offer such a basic class  that is present all over in other programming languages.

Too bad that TStringGrid.Cells is tied to a LARGE visual control.

Comment: Theoretically it's *nothing more* than disabling controls, bookmarking the current cursor position, moving the cursor by the `RecNo` to `Y`, reading and returning a value by `Fields[X]`, moving to the bookmarked cursor position and enabling controls.

Comment: @TLama-Thanks a lot - I will look into this now. I am a bit afraid in digging into such a large an complex class. Can you share your insights about the speed of TDataTable? I store data in mine like this: FRows: array of TStringDynArray so the access is pretty fast. It seems that TDataTable does a lot of extra stuff before accessing the data.

Comment: Strange is that if you put 'delphi' and 'table' in Google you won't find a single result which is not related to some kind of DB (in most of the cases, BDE).

Comment: `TDataSet` is a slow beast no matter how good its implementors do their work. If you're going to work with a string table, dynamic arrays are the right choice I'd say (maybe a sparse one). Maybe you might consider some index links (don't know a term for this). Arrays of integers that link to the final indices in the storage array. With such index links you can do sorting just over that array, and if you'll be inserting a new column, you won't need to insert it but actually append to the end and only insert the index to that index link array on proper position.

Comment: I agree with @TLama about TDataSet; it does come with a lot of baggage.  Otoh, it's not particularly difficult to implement a custom TDataSet with a parallel interface that enables you to "go behind" the TDataSet wrapper when you want to.  Marco Cantu has a nice example of a v. simple custom dataset - http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20587

Comment: Looks like I am going to stick with my own class. Thank you both !!!!

Comment: @TLama-Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?